# Como consumir dados online em um Adapter

Tags: android, android-adapter

Com esse código Adapter abaixo criei uma galeria que funciona sem problema, mas ao invés de consumir as imagens do Drawable eu quero que consuma as imagens que estão na web. Alguém sabe como faço para obter esse resultado?

```
public class GaleriaImagensAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private Context context;
private int[] imagens = new int[] { R.drawable.min_interface_13, R.drawable.min_interface_14, R.drawable.min_interface_132 };

GaleriaImagensAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return imagens.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view.equals(object);
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup pager, int position, Object object) {
    ((ViewPager) pager).removeView((ImageView) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup pager, int position) {
    ImageView imagem = new ImageView(context);
    imagem.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
    imagem.setImageResource(imagens[position]);
    ((ViewPager) pager).addView(imagem, 0);
    return imagem;
}
```

Comment: Você precisa mandar a lista (das urls  das imagens) pro seu adpter pelo construtor

Comment: Esse é o ponto, não tem como montar essa lista com a url das imagens, pois quero pegar as imagens de uma pagina do Facebook e carregar dentro da galeria. O Facebook tem uma API que faz a liberação, mas não consigo implementar um código q mostre as imagens no app